# Passing and modifying array of vectors through functions in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, reference, stl

(I'm from C background and new in C++ and its STLs)
I'm writing a C++ array of vectors that will be passed (as a reference of an array of vectors) through a function and will be processed in it.
 
In this case [in C] I would have passed a pointer to my custom data type (call by value under the hood.)
My code that's giving errors in compile time while trying to do so:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

/* 
the problem is I can't get the syntax. vector<type> &var is
a reference to a single dimension array of vectors.   
*/

void pass_arrayOf_vect(vector<int> &array, int lmt);

int main() {

  int lmt = 10;

  vector<int> lst[lmt];

  pass_arrayOf_vect(lst, lmt);

  return 0;
}

/*
and the traditional ambiguity of whether using "."  or "->" for 
accessing or modifying indexes and their members.
*/

void pass_arrayOf_vect(vector<int> &lst, int lmt) {


      for (int i = 0; i < lmt; i++) {

          lst[i].push_back(i*i);

      }


      for (int i = 0; i < lmt; i++) {
        printf("array[%d]: ", i);
        for (int j = 0; j < lst[i].size(); j++) {

            printf("%d ",lst[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
      }

     printf("\n");

     return;
}
```

Comment: To use an array of vectors write `vector<vector<int>>`.

Comment: careful with `vector<int> lst[lmt];` Because `lmt` isn't a compile-time constant, this is what's called a Variable Length Array. They are not a part of Standard C++ and only a few compilers support them. Makes life messy if you build your program in GCC and submit the program to someone using Visual Studio.

Comment: Since your from C, you should probably know straight away that the C++ standard doesn't support variable length arrays (VLAs) as you have here (and even the rogue compilers that support it by extension will probably puke at the site of a non-POD-type for the element base), so I'd start by steering clear of those. Second, anytime you have questions about reported compiler errors on this site (as you said, "...giving errors in compile time" **always** include the errors *verbatim* in your post.

Comment: @WhozCraig got the point. so what is the standard practice ? modifying an array of vector in main() or in other function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `main` function the `lst` variable is an array of vectors. When you pass this to the `pass_arrayOf_vect` function you pass a pointer to the first element.

I.e. when you do

```
pass_arrayOf_vect(lst, lmt);
```

it's actually the same as doing

```
pass_arrayOf_vect(&lst[0], lmt);
```

So the function you call needs to accept a *pointer* to a vector as its first argument (not a reference):

```
void pass_arrayOf_vect(vector<int> *array, int lmt);
//                                 ^
// Note use of asterisk instead of ampersand
```

---

An even better solution would be to use an [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) of vectors instead. Or if you're on an older compiler without support for `std::array`, or need the amount to be run-time configurable (in which case you can't use plain C-style arrays anyway), use a vector of vectors.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to know. so what is the standard practice ? modifying an array of vector in main() or in other function ?

Comment: @ph03n1x Where you modify a vector depends on your program, and what you're trying to do and accomplish. For a simple program such as your it doesn't matter, except that using a function or two might increase readability.

Comment: For now I'm using C++ mainly for programming problem solving. and later would use it for Linux Kernel/System programming (if needed.)